# how to copy text line by line from shape in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

how can I copy text line by line (and possibly with formatting) from a shape to a cell in Excel vba?

the result should look similar to this:
[image]

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should get you in the ballpark:

```
Sub WriteOutShapeText(shapeName As String)

    'get the values from the shape called whatever is stored in shapeName
    'and split the text into an array using chr(11) (line feed)
    Dim textArray As Variant
    textArray = Split(Sheet1.Shapes(shapeName).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text, Chr(11))


    'Set up the row to which we will start writing
    Dim writeRow As Integer
    writeRow = 1

    'Loop through the array assigning each element in textArray to the variable textline
    For Each textLine In textArray

        'write out to sheet1 column 1 starting at writeRow
        Sheet1.Cells(writeRow, 1).Value = textLine

        'increment to the next row to which we will write
        writeRow = writeRow + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

You can use it in VBA like:

```
Call WriteOutShapeText("Rectangle 1")
```

just change "Rectangle 1" to whatever you shape is called and change the range that it writes out to, to wherever you want it to go.